# Proof using Order Field

Tags: proof-writing, axioms

given that $F$ is an ordered field, and $a \in F$ , prove that $a^2 \geq 0$,

Now From the axiom that given $x,y \in F$ either $x \leq y$ or $y \leq x$, its obvious that there is 2 choices for $a$.

either $a \geq 0$ and in this case we know that $a^2 = a*a \geq 0$ because for any $x,y \in F$ if $x \geq 0$ and $y \geq 0$ then $x y \geq 0$.

Help me prove the case when $a \leq 0$ i know that $-a \geq 0$ so $-a *-a \geq 0$ and $(-1)*a = -a = a*(-1)$ , so what to do from here using only the axioms ?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing you need to prove is that 
$$(-1)*(-1)=1\tag{1}.$$
If this is done then
$$(-a)*(-a)=(-1)*a*(-1)*a=(-1)*(-1)*a*a=1*a*a=a*a.$$

To prove (1), use
$$0=(1+(-1))*(-1)=1*(-1)+(-1)*(-1)=-1+(-1)*(-1).$$
So $1=(-1)*(-1)$.

Comment: its all looks fine but how you get from $(-1)*a*(-1)*a $ to $(-1)*(-1)*a*a$ ,what axiom you used ?

Comment: Multiplication is commutative. (If you do not assume $F$ to be a commutative field, then this is still true since $a*(-1)=(-1)*a$, and use associativity.)